# Laptop and PC Synchronization over Wireless Network

Tags: backup, sync

I want to synchronize my laptop with pc. I have installed mirrorfolder but its not useful.

I want my files up to date in both computers please let me know if there is any reliable way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Live Sync](http://sync.live.com) works very well for this.

Very easy to set up and use.  It is very reliable and very efficient with your bandwidth.  It will use a LAN connection if one is available or sync over the internet if necessary.  I have used it to sync >15GB of photos without any problem.

Comment: I do not want to involve internet. Is it possible to do it without having internet?

Comment: If the two machines are on the same local network, the sync will happen over the network only (and it will be much faster)

Answer (score 1):

The freeware [Allwaysync](http://allwaysync.com/) meets all my syncing needs.  Sync can be scheduled or triggered by events.  Very flexible in terms of sync direction, what gets overwritten, how many backup copies are kept, and so on.